# Saving Image from phonegap app to phone gallery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a Phonegap Build app which contains image gallery. I want to save image from Phonegap app to mobile gallery by clicking save button. I tried several options and posted a question on StackOverflow

[Saving Image From phonegap App to Mobile gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664557/saving-image-from-phonegap-app-to-mobile-gallery)

And tried other ways to download image from app but no code is working.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function' <br>'(fileSystem) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/image");
    var path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "appName/example.jpg";

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        path,
        function(entry) {
            refreshMedia.refresh(path); // Refresh the image gallery
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error.source);
            console.log(error.target);
            console.log(error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: You cannot save pictures to 'the gallery' as the Gallery app is an app and no storage place. So please be clear. Tell us to which storage place you try to save the image.

Comment: sd card or phone storage where possible

Comment: Indeed. Now what is the problem? You are pretty vague.

Comment: i want to save active picture in phonestorage

Comment: i already tried this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664557/saving-image-from-phonegap-app-to-mobile-gallery but its not working

Comment: I will not follow that link. Put your code here as it will be only a few lines. And 'it's not working' is a very bad description is you want help. You should come to the point instead. You should exactly tell which errors and exceptions and how your code flows.

Comment: i edited my question and added the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133268/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-and-greenapps).

Comment: `no code working for me please help me solve this issue `  ??? Well what does not work? Give a full error report please.

Comment: when i call this function it doesnot show any download message or not showing any error

Comment: Strange. What is the value of `var path` ? Which Android version in use?

Comment: `var uri = encodeURI("www/img/img1.jpg");  //stored in phonegap img directory`<br>
``var path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "myappname/image1.jpg";

Comment: You are only repeating yourself. I did not ask for code to determine a path. I wanted to know which path exactly.

Comment: "myappname/image1.jpg";

Comment: i am doubtfull about calling the function .i am calling the function after deviceready like this . window.requestFileSystem();

Comment: sorry for my bad English .I am not good in English

Comment: `"myappname/image1.jpg";` Impossible of course as the complete `path` is `path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "myappname/image1.jpg"`.You should tell us the complete path.

Comment: yes exectly the same path i tried

Comment: path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "myappname/image1.jpg";

Comment: My god... what is the path exactly? What is 'path' if you log or print it? What is its value?

Comment: did you mean path of image in app

Comment: "www/img/img1.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I give up.

Comment: i can't understand which path you are asking for

Comment: `var path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "myappname/image1.jpg"`